# Forms authentication not authenticating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I've set up the following forms authentication based on what I understand from the MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit for MCTS exam 70-562, but it isn't authenticating...

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="ortund" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>

<location path="Members">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Basically it needs to allow unauthenticated users access to all areas of the site except for `~/Members/` and all files and folders inside there.

Currently all it's doing is constantly just redirecting back to the login page... Is there a concept I'm missing here? I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Here's the code for the login:

```
Protected Sub lnkLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkLogin.Click
    Dim db As New Database

    ' gets data from the database with the supplied credentials
    ' if true, the user exists, proceed to log in
    If db.Login(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text, "ortund") Then
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtEmail.Text, True)

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params("ReturnUrl")) Then
            Response.Redirect(Request.Params("ReturnUrl"))
        Else
            Response.Redirect("~/Members/Default.aspx")
            'Response.Redirect("~/AboutUs.aspx")
        End If
    Else
        lblerr.Text = "Invalid username or password"
    End If
End Sub
```

And the Page_Load for Members/Default.aspx:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            loadUserPage()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: By my understanding this should work, allowing a 30 minute timeout that resets when the user performs an action...

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaand after 2 maddening hours of deafening sweet stuff all on SO, IRC, Facebook, and Skype... Here's how I fixed this one:

I created a test application just to make sure that I had the concept right. The test differed only from the above in that it used credentials specified in the web.config file for the login whereas the actual project queried the database for the user credentials.

You can download my test code [here](http://www.loganyoung.za.net/code/FormsAuth.zip) (it uses .NET 4, but you can apply the same authentication elements in the web.config file to an earlier framework as well).

Because this test case works, I can be sure that the problem isn't in the code, and that means it's a setup issue.

**The Solution**
The fix in this case was simple. I deleted the Virtual Application from IIS and recreated it with a .NET 4.0 Classic AppPool.